# PHP MySQL Insert Not working properly for a specific value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple program that will track login attempts on my application. Basically, every time someone tries to log in, I store his/her IP, username, and whether his/her login was successful or not. I use 1 to indicate a successful login and a 0 to indicate an unsuccessful login attempt.

While my program is working well for successful logins, when I make an unsuccessful login attempt, the username does not seem to show up in the table.

```
$status; //An integer that holds the 1s and 0s

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Logins (User, IP, Status) VALUES ('$user', '$ip', $status)");
```

That's pretty much all there is. Works just fine for 1s but does not show the username whenever I use 0. I have tried multiple approaches but nothing works.

Any ideas?

An image of what my table looks like:

[image]

**Edit:** My problem got solved! Thanks to everyone who helped. It seems my program had not a syntactical, but rather, a very bad logical error. Your solutions - echoing queries - helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is not very much to go on here, do you have error checking in place?

Comment: and what is the datatype for that in DB if its varchar or enum you need to use quotes for the input value `'$status'`

Comment: It was initially INT. But when that didn't work, I changed it to CHAR(3) and used quotes around $status, i.e. '$status'.

Comment: But still didn't work.

Comment: What is the actual error (message) then?

Comment: I've edited my post to show you what my table looks like.

Comment: @rouby I'm not getting an error message! That's the problem! Just that when $status is 0, it doesn't insert the username.

Comment: Did you echo the statements (like suggested in an "answer" below)?

Comment: @MadhavNarayan use single quote for status in values may be its help to you...

Comment: debug it...check your getting the right values through, print the query, turn on php errors, execute the query directly in the database. Doesn't seem like you've tried anything to debug it.

Comment: @MadhavNarayan CARE to check Answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Logins (User, IP, Status) VALUES ('".$user."', '".$ip."', '".$status."')");
```

Firstly Check if setting Hardcoded values works , if Yes then Dynamic values also should work .If no then something Wrong with your Query.

Now Check running query in Query prompt of mysql.If query works then its Connection issue with DB.

Comment: Yep. Hardcoded values work. Okay let me play around with my query.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your query:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Logins (User, IP, Status) 
                           VALUES ('$user', '$ip', $status)");
```

To:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO Logins (User, IP, Status)
                           VALUES ('".$user."', '".$ip."', '".$status."')");
```